# Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined in impure pipe

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-pipe

I am trying to create an impure language pipe, but getting the error
`Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined` when I call
`this.languageService.translate(key)` in languagePipe.

**LanguagePipe:**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { LanguageService } from './language.service';

@Pipe({
    name:'lang',
    pure: false
})
export class LanguagePipe implements PipeTransform {


    private inCycle;
    private value = null;

    constructor(
        private languageService: LanguageService) { }

    transform = (key: string): string => {
        
        if (!key || typeof key == "undefined") {
            return "";
        }
        
        if (this.value && this.inCycle == this.languageService.getLang()) {
            return this.value;
        }
        
        if(this.inCycle != this.languageService.getLang()) {
            this.inCycle = this.languageService.getLang();

            this.languageService.translate(key)
                .subscribe((response: string) => {
                    this.value = response;
                }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

**in service:**

```
public translate = (key: string): Observable<string> => {
        
        // Drop back an empty string if key is invalid
        if (key == "" || key == "null" || typeof key == "undefined" || key == "undefined") {
            return new Observable((observer) => {
                observer.next('');
            }); 
        }

        //If the language have not exist yet, create the empty object
        if (!this.cache.getCache("language")) {
            this.cache.setCache("language",{});
        }

        // Get text from cache
        let cachedValue = this.cache.getCacheRecursive("language", this._currentLang + "/data/" + key); 
        if (cachedValue) {
            console.log('returning from translate2')
            return new Observable((observer) => {
                observer.next(cachedValue);
            });
        }

        // Call server for page texts if page not exists yet and call not started yet
        let page = this.getPageId();

        if (!this.isPageExists(page) && !this.langPackCallInProgress) {
            let value = '';
            return this.getLangPack(page, key)
                .pipe(map((response: string) => {
                    value = response;
                    return value;
                }
            ));
        }


        // Call server for only one text if page exists and key is missing
        //return this.translateKey(key);
    }



    // getting language pack for whole page
    private getLangPack(page, key): Observable<string> {
        let url = this.requestPaths[1] + "?page=" + page + "&lang=" + this._currentLang;
        let isCommonRequested = false;
        let value: string;
        if (!this.isPageExists("common")) {
            url += "&needCommon=true";
            isCommonRequested = true;
        }

        if (!this.isPageExists(page)) {
            this.langPackCallInProgress = true;
            return this.httpClientService.postData(url, '')
                .pipe(map((response: MessageResource[]) => {

                    //Put texts to the cache
                    for(let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                        this.cache.setCacheRecursive("language", this._currentLang + "/data/" + response[i].resourceKey, response[i].value);   
                    }

                    this.setPageExists(page);
                    if (isCommonRequested) {
                        this.setPageExists("common");
                    }
                    for(let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                        if(response[i]["resourceKey"] === key) {
                            value = response[i]["value"];
                        }
                    }
                    this.langPackCallInProgress = false;
                    return value;
                }

            ));
        }
    }
```

**error:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
    at LanguagePipe.transform (language.pipe.ts:38)
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (LoginButtonComponent.html:5)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:45293)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44276)
    at callViewAction (core.js:44636)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:44593)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44271)
    at callViewAction (core.js:44636)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:44564)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44277)
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Did you debug through it? Your function does not always return a value because you commented the last bit out

Comment: can you add the error log

Comment: @MikeS Yes commented the last bit out, because it would request the server for only that MessageResource value, but first I'd like to request the whole MessageResource array for the specific page and cache it. That commented out bit is kind of a last resort in case something is missing from the array from the first call. Would be too expensive to get the message resources one by one

Comment: @bubbles added the error log

Comment: You should debug through the code and observe whether or not it does end up returning a `observable`

Comment: Also if your function does have a return type, every path in the function should be returning a value, not just some.

Comment: thank you for your resonse. I think the problem is that I don't subscribe anywhere to that getLangPack() method directly, so it doesn't even happen..

Comment: i don't see any getLang() method in service